# bar chart with textual x axis - achartengine

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, achartengine

I am using achartengine's bar chart in my application. My x axis is not numeric but has text items. just like the pic shown below. Is there a way to make a bar graph like this using achartengine? Can I only display the text in the x axis and not the scale?

[image]

Comment: I want to display above chart with horizontal bar, and i want to display red, yellow, purple, green, blue from bottom to top..

give me suggestion for that.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 8):

I had a problem with `clearXTextLabels()` too, try this:

```
renderer.setXlabels(0);
renderer.addXTextLabel(0,"Electronics");
renderer.addXTextLabel(1,"Medical");
...
```

Comment: I want to set distance between two bar how can i do it? Did you know?

Comment: I want to display above chart with horizontal bar, and i want to display red, yellow, purple, green, blue from bottom to top.. 

give me suggestion for that. 

Thanks in Advance